# Counting new lines in Ada

Tags: performance, ada

I'm trying to write an efficient program to count the number of new line characters from standard input. I wrote the following program:

```vhdl
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   New_Lines : Integer := 0;
begin
   while not Ada.Text_IO.End_Of_File loop
      declare
         Line : String := Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line;
      begin
         New_Lines := New_Lines + 1;
      end;
   end loop;

   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Integer'Image(New_Lines));
end Main;
```

How can this be made more efficient? I'm noticing that the compiler warns about not using `Line`. Maybe there's a way of specifying that I'm just interested in skipping to the new line character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Ada.Text_IO.Skip_Line` instead, to avoid storing the lines on the stack, and getting rid of the warning about `Line` you mention.

A mofified version of your program:

```vhdl
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   New_Lines : Integer := 0;
begin
   while not Ada.Text_IO.End_Of_File loop
      Ada.Text_IO.Skip_Line;
      New_Lines := New_Lines + 1;
   end loop;
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Integer'Image(New_Lines));
end Main;
```

This is not guaranteed to count the last line, though, unless the *file terminator* is directly preceeded by a *line terminator*. (Although it seems at least GNAT will count it)

Be aware that on some platforms, the *line terminator* is not just a new line character, on windows, for example, it is CR+LF.